# Is it possible to sync with different server database in a single app

Tags: android, database

I want to make an Android App, where I want to sync with different server database to store my data. Like for example Firebase database, AWS Database etc and sync accross them same time. Also with different firebase database account at the same time vise versa with AWS too

Any clue anyone, is it possible? If it is will there be latency during synchronisation.

Comment: nothing prevents you from writing synchronization code for each of these and all api's have _some_ sort of latency, not sure what more you want as an answer ?

Comment: I just needed the confirmation, is it even possible with different firebase Account Database at the same time syncing ??